# Why does 0 % 5 return 0?

Tags: python

I am making a game of pong right now, and I want the ball to speed up every 5 hits, but when I run the ball just starts speeding off in its starting direction.

It runs fine without the speeding up of the ball so the problem isn't previous code.

When trying to implement this I made a variable in my Ball class called `self.num_hits` and made it initially 0. Then in my game loop every time the ball collides, I increment the `ball.num_hits` and reverse its x_speed.

```
collide_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(ball, players, False)
if collide_list != []:
    ball.x_speed *= -1
    hit.play()
    ball.num_hits += 1
```

In the Ball() class:

```
if self.num_hits % 5 == 0:
        if self.x_speed > 0:
            self.x_speed += 2
        else:
            self.x_speed -= 2
```

But that made the ball speed off in its starting velocity, so I checked what `self.num_hits % 5` was returning, and it always returns 0. I always thought that `0 % number = number`, so my question is why does 0 % 5 return 0? And is there any other way I can make the ball speed up every 5 hits if I can't get around the 0 % 5 problem?

Comment: Because 0 divides anything.

Comment: X % Y will never return Y if Y != 0, I suppose.

Comment: The remainder after 0 is divided by 5 is 0

Comment: @squiguy: 0 divides only 0.  0 is divisible by anything.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes, that's what I meant to say.

Comment: `x % y == z` means there is some `a` such that `a * y + z == x` and `z` is between 0 and `y-1`. If `x` is 0, then `z` and `y` are 0, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Division is defined so that the following is always true

> *n* = *q*  × *d* + *r*

where

- *n* is the numerator (or dividend),
- *d* != 0 is the denominator (or divisor),
- *q* is the quotient, and
- *r* > 0 is the remainder.

(This holds for positive and negative values; *q* is positive if *n* and *d* have the same sign and negative otherwise. *r* is defined to be always positive.)

In Python, `n/d == q` and `n % d == r`. If `n` is 0, then `q` must also be 0, in which case `r` must be 0 as well—all independent of the value of `d`.

(Off-topic, but note that this also captures the problem with division by 0: for non-zero *d*, *q* and *r* are uniquely determined; for *d* = 0, *any* value of *q* will satisfy the equation for *r = n*.

Answer (score 4):

Why does 0 % 5 return 0?

Because:

Zero divided by five is zero, remains zero.

```
0 % 5 = 0
12 % 5 = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

a % n is the same as a - (n * int(a/n)).  0/5 equals 0 because 5 goes in to 0, 0 times.  0 * 5 is 0.  0 minus 0 is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try if self.num_hits / 5 == 0:

Comment: That wouldn't execute every 5 hits though. This would give me the same problem I already have because self.num_hits == 0 would constantly return True at the start of the game making the ball speed off

Answer (score 1):

number_1 % number_2 =>is the remainder when you divide number_1 by number_2

which in 0 % any_number case is always 0.

Answer (score 1):

*0 % 5 = 0*
1 % 5 = 1
2 % 5 = 2
3 % 5 = 3
4 % 5 = 4
5 % 5 = 0
6 % 5 = 1
7 % 5 = 2
...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is taught in primary school, but this has a simple answer.
% gives you the remainder of the division problem. If you have (for example) `6 % 5` you would get `1`, because 5 goes into 6 one time, and `5 * 1 == 5`. `6-5 == 1`, which is the answer. Here is `0%5` and 5 goes into 0 (shockingly) zero times. `5*0 == 0`, and `0-0 == 0`. Therefore,