# Python: the result of (8%3) is 2 but (-8%3) is 1. shouldn't it be -2? and why?

Tags: python

Here is the proof:

```
-8 == -2 * 3 - 2
```

that means `-8%3` should be equal to `-2`. 
but python returns `1` and it's driving me crazy

Comment: It **is** equal to 1...

Comment: Both ways work (with the matching convention for integer division), but it's more practical from a programming standpoint if the result of a % b is always in [0 .. b).

Comment: It is math, not programming.

Comment: -8/3 is also -3, so your example starts with a faulty premise. Just because your equation is true doesn't mean that's how division is defined.

Comment: My [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15594441/1126841) to a related question may be illuminating.

Comment: Seems like every programming language has their opinion : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 10):

In python, the sign matches the denominator.

```
>>> -8 % 3
1
>>> -8 % -3
-2
```

For an explanation of why it was implemented this way, read the [blog post by Guido](http://python-history.blogspot.com.au/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html).

Comment: From the docs "The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its second operand (or zero); the absolute value of the result is strictly smaller than the absolute value of the second operand".  This agrees with that as well.

Answer (score 5):

integer math is funny:

```
>>> -8//3  # (-8/3 in python2 does the same thing)
-3
>>> 8//3   # (8/3 in python2 does the same thing)
2
>>>
```

Rounding is done *down*, not towards zero.

Comment: "Rounding is done *towards zero*, not just down." - but the interpreter snippet shows the exact opposite.

Comment: Python division is floored, towards negative infinity, not truncated, towards 0.

Comment: Sorry guys, my example was correct, my wording was reversed

Comment: Did you know you can use `//` on any Python since 2.2? The only thing that changed is the way `/` works on integers.

Comment: @MarkRansom I did not. Apparently you can even do it on explicit floats, and get a floored float back (`4.0 // 3.0 -> 1.0`)

Comment: it's more necessary in Python3 where dividing 2 ints gives you a float.  As a result, even in 2, if your intention is integer division, you should be using `//`

Answer (score 1):

```
 3%3 = 0
 2%3 = 2
 1%3 = 1
 0%3 = 0
-1%3 = 2
-2%3 = 1
-3%3 = 0

...

-7%3 = 2
-8%3 = 1
```

Be careful:
    (-8)%3  !=  -(8%3)

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at (one common interpretation of) integer division:

Given `a, b, d, r in N` and `b > 0` and `0 <= r < b`, then:

`a // b = d` and `a % b = r`

iff

`a = d * b + r`.

Hence: From `-8 = -3 * 3 + 1` and `-8 // 3 = -3` follows `-8 % 3 = 1`

---

```
>>> -8 == -3 * 3 + 1
True
>>> -8 // 3 
-3
>>> -8 % 3
1
>>> (-8 // 3) * 3 + (-8 % 3) == -8
True
```

Comment: thanks I rememberd in highschool they thought us:
-2|1

Answer (score 0):

-8 = -3*3 + 1

In math the rest is ALWAYS positive so that in **a = m*k + r** k is integer and r is integer but with 0 <= r < |m|